# drag the points of the curve to change the shape of the curve in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, fl-chart

I'm building a flutter application that includes line charts, and it would be good to have the user be able to drag and drop points to have it update. Would such a thing be possible? And if so is there any example of such a thing being done?

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=line-draggable

Comment: Hi bro! Have you found any solution for that? I want exactly the same behavior, I'm using the fl_chart package.